# How to hydrate react ssr with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, server-side, styled-components

I am building a react ssr. I decided to use styled-components for css to try css-in-js. I got this error on the console:

```
react-dom.development.js:530 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "Home__StyledHome-s26o42-0 frotjg" Client: "Home__StyledHome-s26o42-0 kCdWHN"
```

note:i did not use "className" at all.

I clicked on "react-dom.development.js:530" and directed to this line

```
Function.prototype.apply.call(console.error, console, argsWithFormat);
```

this is server side renderer function where we render the html:

```
import { ServerStyleSheet, StyleSheetManager } from "styled-components";

export default (req, store, context) => {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();

  try {
    const content = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
          <StyleSheetManager sheet={sheet.instance}>
            <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
          </StyleSheetManager>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags();
    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    return `
    <html>
    <head>
    ${helmet.title.toString()}
    ${helmet.meta.toString()}
    ${styleTags}
    </head>
    <body>
    <div  id="root">${content}</div>
    <script>window.INITIAL_STATE=${serialize(store.getState())}</script>
    <script src="bundle.js"> </script>
    </body></html> `;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  } finally {
    sheet.seal();
  }
};
```

this is the client side hydrate function:

```
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";
//StyleSheetManager: documentation says do not use in the client side.
const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

since this did not work I implemented this but it did not work neither:
server-side:

```
export default (req, store, context) => {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();

  try {
    const content = renderToString(
      sheet.collectStyles(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
            <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
      )
    );
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags();
    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    return `
    <html> 
    <head>
    ${helmet.title.toString()}
    ${helmet.meta.toString()}
    ${styleTags}
    </head>
    <body>
    <div  id="root">${content}</div>
    <script>window.INITIAL_STATE=${serialize(store.getState())}</script>
    <script src="bundle.js"> </script>
    </body></html> `;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("style-component server-site", e);
  } finally {
    sheet.seal();
  }
};
```

client-side:

```
const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
ReactDOM.hydrate(
  sheet.collectStyles(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  )
);
```

documentation of styled-components with react-ssr is very short. I implement the way how API is supposed to be but still got this error. this topic is a little confusing, I hope someone can help.

Comment: did u find a way to fix it or want some help?